# How can I set control properties when my form is loading or initialized (by atributes or without)?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, attributes

I have searched but I couldn't find the answer.There is the form witch users can set the property for some controls like buttons, textBox and etc.I  would like to be able to set these properties(whitch users choosed) when all the forms are loading or initialized.Is there any attribute for setting these properties?

whats the best way? (the project has 20 forms and every form has more than 10 controls)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the form's Load event handler and set properties there. For example:

```
public void MyForm_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTextBox.Text = "Hello!";
}
```

Comment: i have more that 15 forms in my project and every form has more than 15 controls.is this good way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form load event

```
public void yourform_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Set attributes here
}
```

Comment: thanx for your reply .I have more that 15 forms in my project and every form has more than 15 controls,is there an other way?